# No logro establecer la conexión entre MySql y C#

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo un problema a la hora de conectar mi base de datos con C#. Tengo el conector en la referencia pero, me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace Datos
{
    public class ConexionBD
    {
        public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
        {
            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=casasenlassierras;");
            conectar.Open();
            return conectar;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: ¿Referenciaste la dll del conector o instalaste el nuget package? Si solo referenciaste la dll, puede que no tengas todos los archivos / dependencias necesarios. Adicionalmente, las excepciones debes incluirlas como texto, no solo como imágenes.